# DBContext Linq to entity read uncommitted

Tags: .net, performance, linq, dbcontext

My question comes in two fold. Firsty, i would normally do something like `entity.ExecuteStoreCommand` when working with the ObjectContext, however this seems like its not the case with DBContext.

- A) I'd thought that if you want to do an uncommitted read on the
  database you would have to set it somewhere is this correct, and
  still the case with DBConext.
- B) Whilst i'd never advocate a dirty read when working with payment details, etc... Do other people find it improves the performance of their linq statements, if so.. does any one have any points of reference stats etc on the matter?

my code example

```
protected String isolationLevel = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;";
 public UserAccountDetail GetUserAccount(string userName, int userId)
        {
            using (var personEntity = new PersonEntity())
            {
                // set isolation level here such as... personEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand(isolationLevel, null);

                userAccountDetails = personEntity.UserAccountDetails.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Username == userName && q.UserID == userId);
            }
        }
```

If Any one has any DBConext pointers that would be phat, regarding performance, best practice etc.

Cheers,
Simps

Comment: Does any one know if Microsoft are going to give ongoing support for DBContext, or if their planning on releasing a new version... should I use it, am I way of the mark?

Comment: What do you mean by "new version"? There will be new versions of Entity Framework that will contain new versions of DbContext. Here is a blog post about EF versioning going forward: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx. Recently the team shipped EF 4.3.1 and EF 5.0.0-beta2. EF 5 is meant for .NET 4.5 and allows to use new features that were added to core libraries in .NET Framework 4.5 (e.g. enums, spatial types, TVFs etc.).

Answer (score 2):

DbContext does not set isolation level. If you need to execute a SQL command using DbContext APIs you can do:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Your SQL statement here");
```

If you need the ObjectContext instance backing your DbContext object you can do the following:

```
var objecCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: Interesting, I think that helps. Do you know why they don't allow you to set the isolation level, is it based on the caching involved in DBContext?

Comment: You can add this idea here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions